# What's the cheapest way to get a PCB assembled?

Tags: pcb

I plan to order some PCB but the components are all smd and tqfp packages and I doubt if I can solder them by myself because of my lack of expierience as well as equipment. Whats the most affordable way to get a PCB assembled? Right now to make PCB's I am using this site:(http://oshpark.com/) since I only need a few of these. Does anyone have any good suggestions?

Comment: Most affordable?  Buy good soldering iron.  Learn how to solder SMT.  Practice a bit.  TQFP can be soldered by hand.  0603 can be soldered by hand.

Comment: I fixed the title of your question. The *easiest* way is to pay someone else to do it. The body of the question made it clear that this isn't what you're asking about.

Comment: Are there any sites as reasonable as oshpark for PCB design that do this?

Comment: The key to hand soldering leaded SMT chips is to use flux and surface tension to distribute the solder.  Only solder one pin, check alignment, solder one in the opposite corner and check again.  It's when you get a lot of pins soldered down with the chip misaligned where you start to need a hot air station, or very painstaking removal with solder braid and a fine steel wire under the pins - so try very hard to avoid getting into that situation!

Answer (score 2):

The cheapest way would be to get a soldering iron and learn to do it yourself. Buy one or two extra boards and kits to learn with (if there's a really expensive part, buy some other, cheaper part in the same package).

For a small lot (like 10 or 20 pieces or less), the next cheapest way would probably be to find somebody to do the assembly by hand with a soldering iron. How you find somebody to do that depends on your geography. If you're in the US, you might try the Craigslist "gigs" board, or one of the other freelancer's web sites.